# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sub' of null in Google Analytics API

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

i created one application which uses google analytics api ie https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=load

and i was using nicely but suddenly now one error is coming 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sub' of null
after popup comes for username and password,

it was working fine before but now it is showing this error.
can anyone please help me out with this.

Thanks,
Mayank

Comment: I'm getting this as of about 20mins ago too! I know it's not a code change I've made because it's started happening on my live sites.

Comment: I don't particularly like google analytics (or google in general) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Analytics#Privacy_issues

Comment: +1 since today, for me it is happening when loading GAPI.

Comment: it is happening for me since today morning

Comment: For me too. I supose it will be a bug in the API

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the Google API Javascript Client, and my production site is being affected as well. A bug report was filed at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=110, and it is currently labeled critical priority by the development team. They have "identified the cause and are working on a fix". Hopefully we'll get one by the end of today.