# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sub' of null in Google drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

at line cb=gapi.loaded_0:282

Earlier it was working fine today I am getting this error Any fix?

similar issue with Google Analytics API

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sub' of null in Google Analytics API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508859/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-sub-of-null-in-google-analytics-api)

Comment: Apparently Google is working on a fix: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=110

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug, and Google is already working on a fix - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=110